# java Arrays.asList() returns something unexpected for char array

Tags: java, arrays, list, casting, char

Recently i came across the situation, that i wantet to convert a char array to a List. However, in the end i needed to solve my problem another way, because what Arrays.asList() returned wasn't what i expected.

Here is a similar piece of code:

```
List l = Arrays.asList(new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'});
l.forEach(System.out::println);   
// output [C@1218025c
```

From my noobish point of view the output should be the characters a,b, and c instead of somthing looking like a memory address ([C@1218025c). As it works for String arrays i found an easy walkaround, but i still wonder what is happening.

Comment: You can't make a `List<char>`, or a `List` of any primitive type. You're getting a 1-element `List<char[]>`.